# CreateUser Function Not Working in AngularFire - Firebase Simple Login?

Tags: firebase, angularfire, firebasesimplelogin

I have the following controller that uses AngularFire

```
app.controller("authController", function($scope, $firebaseSimpleLogin){

var ref = new Firebase("https://myapp.firebaseIO.com/");
$scope.auth = $firebaseSimpleLogin(ref, function(error, user){
    if(error){
        console.log(error);
    }
    else if(user){
        console.log(user);
    }
    else{
        console.log("user logged out");
    }
});

// This shows a valid object
console.log($scope.auth);

$scope.createAccount = function(){
    console.log("found me");
    $scope.auth.$createUser($scope.email, $scope.password, function(error, user){
        console.log("something");
        console.log(user);
        if(!error){
            console.log(user);
        }
        else{
            console.log(error);
        }
    });
};

});
```

When I bind the `$scope.createAccount` function to an `ng-click` event and click on the bound button, `console.log("found me")` runs in the browser, but none of the other `console.log` commands in `$scope.createAccount` is shown.

The `console.log($scope.auth)` command I have before setting the `$scope.createAccount` function shows a valid object with the `$createUser` function defined.

I am not receiving any console errors when I run `$scope.createAccount` so I am assuming the call has been "successfully" made.

Why am I able to see the auth object, but not receiving a callback after calling `$createUser`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This was happening because I was doing callbacks based on JavaScript notation instead of Angular notation.  Since I was using the AngularFire methods (they have the same names as the vanilla JavaScript SDK methods, but with a `$` sign in front of them), I needed to handle callbacks using Angular's `$promise` methodology.

I changed

```
$scope.auth.$createUser($scope.email, $scope.password, function(error, user){
    // do things;
});
```

to

```
$scope.auth.$createUser($scope.email, $scope.password)
    .then(function(user){
        // do things if success
    }, function(error){
        // do things if failure
    });
```

and the callback worked as expected.

There is an exception to the above with the vanilla JS `firebaseSimpleLogin` constructor vs Angular `$firebaseSimpleLogin` constructor.  On the vanilla JS constructor, there are callbacks on the constructor that allows you to specify what your script should do when a user logs in / logs out.  It follows the following format:

```
var auth = new firebaseSimpleLogin(ref, function(error, user){
    if(error){
        // do things if login failure
    }
    else if(user){
        // do things when login succeeds 
    }
    else{
        // do things when user logs out
    }
});
```

If you try to do the same with the Angular constructor like so:

```
$scope.auth = $firebaseSimpleLogin(ref)
    .then(function(user){
        // do things when login succeeds 
    }, function(error){
        // do things when login fails     
    });
```

you'll receive an error.  There are no callback methods with the Angular constructor.  I am guessing this was done on purpose since with Angular, you have data binding and you can simply `$watch` `$scope.auth.user` for changes and perform operations in your app depending on the variable's state.  When `$scope.auth.user` is set to `null`, the user is logged out.  If the value is set to anything else than `null`, then the user is logged in.

Comment: As of 12/31/2014 there is still a bug in the $createUser method. See https://github.com/firebase/angularfire/issues/507

Comment: @RonHarlev: Yeah, the bug is still there. Argh.